# Titanium Studio - Java returns error 13

Tags: java, windows, sdk, titanium

I am trying to install titanium studio on my computer, it is windows 8 64bit ... but every time I start it returns me this error:

[image]

Help me please.

Comment: You need to tell me what version and update of Java you have installed.

Comment: What version of Java are you running (32/64)? This error commonly happens when you have a mismatch of bitness between Eclipse (Which Titanium Studio appears to use) and Java.

Comment: Have you checked this link. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java isn't in your system path, if you have Java 8 Update 25, your path would be:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin
```

Search for `Environment Variables` in Charms sidebar. Then find the variable `Path` and add the path I wrote above followed by a semicolon to separate other entries that are there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid future problems, write this line of code ("-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin") in your eclipse.ini always below this line('--launcher.appendVmargs'), and you can skip errors.

Pd: "jre1.8.0_40" ,if you got Java SE Enviroment Runtime 8, so find out what Java version you are using.